# How do I change the login requirement in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I made my laravel application authentication via `php artisan make:auth` which by default requires you to log in with your email and password.

I need to include another requirement where `status == active` on my table users. So that for a user to log in the three condations:

1. Has a valid `email`
2. Has a valid `password`
3. The status on the users table for that particular use is `active` (this is activated manually)

So on my login controller I have this:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    // protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    public function authenticate()
    {
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) 


        {
            // Authentication passed...
            return redirect()->intended('/home');
        }
    }
}
```

How do insert this condition in the function

```
  DB::table('users')
    ->where(['status' => active]); For that particular user?
```

Kindly someone assist.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add extra conditions to the authentication query in addition to the user's e-mail and password. For example, we may verify that user is marked as "active":

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'status' => 'active'])) {
    // The user is active, not suspended, and exists.
}
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#authenticating-users)

Comment: Thank you, this is all I needed!

Comment: @Amit How do you make sure the custom authenticate function is called? Is it via a route?

Comment: Didn't get your question.